# thinkpad keyboard layout not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I have a Portuguese (pt-br) keyboard on my thinkpad and it have by default a special key that its not on standard place. They key is the "Question Mark + Slash".

To make it work I always use the following command:

```
sudo setxkbmap -model thinkpad60 -layout br
```

But since my last update of elementary (01.March.2017) this command does not work anymore, so now the key is dead.

I found a way to enable it temporarily, but it only works for the active session. After restarting, I need to do the process again:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuratio
```

So, is there a way to setup it correctly? Without losing the settings after restart?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many researches I found what was happening. The settings (from thinkpad + br) was being interfered by an additional options added by another model (korean).

How I solved:

First, checking the layout info with:

```
# setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      thinkpad60
layout:     br
options:    korean:ralt_rctrl,grp:shifts_toggle
```

Second, setting options to *none* with empty quotes:

```
# setxkbmap -model thinkpad60 -layout br -option ''
```

Now all the keyboard is working fine, AltGr, question mark + slash, characters used with AltGr.

**In addiction, add the same command line in the .bashrc file (on your home folder) on the last line file. It will run the script everytime you resume  from sleep mode.**